# Print Order Error Generated From my Account 'My Orders' Section

Tags: orders, error, invoice, print

Yesterday we installed a complete theme on our Magento website. We create a demo order by registering itself to test this procedure so we tried to print out the order invoice from my account option 'My Orders' but after click on it a long error is generated and I don't know how to fix it, please help me to fix this error, below we discussed this entire error.

```
Invalid method Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head::addEMItem(Array
(
    [0] => skin_css
    [1] => css/em_variation.css
    [2] => Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element Object
        (
        )

    [3] => general_disable_frontend_variation
    [4] => 1
)
)

Trace:
#0 [internal function]: Varien_Object->__call('addEMItem', Array)
#1 [internal function]: Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head->addEMItem('skin_css', 'css/em_variatio...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), 'general_disable...', '1')
#2 /home4/siraj786/public_html/dattaexpress/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(348): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#3 /home4/siraj786/public_html/dattaexpress/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(214): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateAction(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#4 /home4/siraj786/public_html/dattaexpress/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(206): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#5 /home4/siraj786/public_html/dattaexpress/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(206): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#6 /home4/siraj786/public_html/dattaexpress/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#7 /home4/siraj786/public_html/dattaexpress/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#8 /home4/siraj786/public_html/dattaexpress/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Controller/Abstract.php(181): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout('print')
#9 /home4/siraj786/public_html/dattaexpress/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Sales_Controller_Abstract->printAction()
#10 /home4/siraj786/public_html/dattaexpress/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('print')
#11 /home4/siraj786/public_html/dattaexpress/app/code/community/BalkeTechnologies/StoreMaintenance/Controller/Router/Standard.php(91): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#12 /home4/siraj786/public_html/dattaexpress/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): BalkeTechnologies_StoreMaintenance_Controller_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#13 /home4/siraj786/public_html/dattaexpress/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#14 /home4/siraj786/public_html/dattaexpress/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#15 /home4/siraj786/public_html/dattaexpress/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#16 {main}
```

Answer (score 1):

The addEMItem is called in the theme layout file.

It seems like your theme module rewrites the Html head block.

Ensure the addEMItem function is declared in the rewritten block and ensure you don't have any other extension rewriting the same block which would result in a conflict.

Comment: So what we need to do it to fix that problem??

Comment: It depends. What did you find regarding my solution ? Is there an addEmItem function declared in the rewritten block ? Or is there any other block rewriting the Html head block ?

Comment: I uninstall all extensions but error still there? which rewritten block you are talking about here?

Comment: Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head

Comment: where we can see or find rewrite code in this theme? if we remove rewrite code then error problem will be resolved??